# How to connect to https server with java application in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, ssl, ca

I have been working on NSDL integration with my java application, in which i have to connect to below web service.

```
https://kra.ndml.in/sms-ws/PANServiceImplService/PANServiceImplService.wsdl
```

so when I hit this service, java application gives me following error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
AxisFault
  faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
  faultSubcode: 
  faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

so i came to know that we have to import the certificate for this service.

So, i get the `nsdl.cer` named certificate from the service provider and then i import it into my java certificates using below keytool command

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file nsdl.cer -alias nsdl -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

then i list the entries present in cacerts file with the following command

`keytool -list -v -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

so i get the entry for nsdl in my certificates and it is shown below

```
*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: nsdl
Creation date: 6 Sep, 2016
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=kra.ndml.in, O=NSDL Database Management Ltd, L=Mumbai, ST=Maharashtra, C=IN
Issuer: CN=SonicWALL Firewall DPI-SSL, O=SonicWALL Inc., ST=CA, C=US
Serial number: a382142c0000000050d5e39b
Valid from: Fri Oct 30 11:12:22 IST 2015 until: Mon Oct 30 11:42:20 IST 2017
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  7E:C5:04:9C:EC:03:BC:96:85:7F:1C:DE:BB:BF:68:F2
     SHA1: 51:8A:DB:37:9B:E8:23:2B:0B:4C:00:3C:26:C2:9D:B9:8E:20:94:CF
     SHA256: 88:B0:E1:86:95:A5:A4:D8:01:89:E3:5D:CF:DF:0F:C3:D3:AE:C6:9E:4B:D2:5B:C6:C9:EE:C2:A3:FD:08:26:15
     Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.13 Criticality=false
0000: 16 27 53 6F 6E 69 63 57   61 6C 6C 20 44 50 49 2D  .'SonicWall DPI-
0010: 53 53 4C 20 2D 20 74 72   75 73 74 65 64 20 63 65  SSL - trusted ce
0020: 72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74   65                       rtificate


#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
SerialNumber: [    c0a8730e ce729dbf]
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

#6: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: kra.ndml.in
  DNSName: www.kra.ndml.in
]



*******************************************
*******************************************
```

so i think that ssl certificate for the above service is included in `jre`

but after this also same `handshake error` is showing.

I don't know how to resolve the issue, since i am new to web services.
Is the process which i am doing is correct, or i have to do something else to connect to `https server`.

I also noticed that in my `nsdl entry in cacerts`, it is like this

```
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
```

whereas in all the entries available before it is `CA:true`

I really got messed up in the above process and don't know what to do, to make it work.

Comment: I got the same error while hitting one of my application servers and found that appwall was blocking the request due to 'possible CSRF attack'.. so please check on this if you can..

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt Thanks I will check for it.